# Can we set the call forwarding programmingly?

Tags: android, ios

Is there a way to setting the number of call forwarding in an iOS/Android application? How?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void callforward(String callForwardString)
    {
        PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
         this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        Uri mmiCode = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");
        intentCallForward.setData(mmiCode);
        startActivity(intentCallForward);
    }

 private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener
 {
        private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;       

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state)
            {
                // phone ringing
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state)
            {
                // active
                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state)
            {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
                // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                if (isPhoneCalling)
                {
                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS this is not possible for a third party app and I'm pretty sure it will never be possible.